# Smooth Shading Issues

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, topology

i am modelling an AK-47 and i have really bad shading issues. here, take a look:

Without smooth shading:

[image]

With smooth shading:

[image]

with smooth shading on, it looks a lot worse. i have bad topology as you can see in this photo:

[image]

i'm pretty sure because of the topology smooth shading is crappy, and if it turns out it is because of topology, how could i fix it?

Comment: How is the title related to the question? Have a look at http://topologyguides.com/

Comment: sorry, for some reason the title switched over to something else, my apologies!

Comment: Try fixing your Normals with Ctrl + N in edit mode with all your vertices selected.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i just needed to use the edge split modifier, it fixed it.

Comment: Modifier doesn't fix it, it hides the problem by preventing smooth shading act on Ngons, long faces and such as long as angle of edges is sharp enough. However in some cases this could be enough

Comment: the answer above is my answer to my own question.